# Why does navigator.productSub always equals '20030107' on Chrome and Safari?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, browser, safari

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.productSub) the archaic `navigator.productSub` property returns the 'build number of the browser'. This probably worked in the nineties, but it's pretty useless now.

However, i'm interested in the numbers that some of the browsers return. Both Chrome and Safari always return the value `20030107`, Firefox seems to return `20100101`. What's the deal with these two numbers? Does `20030107` stand for July 1st, 2003? And what happened then that was so interesting?

Here's hoping someone can dig up a little web history.

Answer (score 6):

First released as a public beta on January 7, 2003[2] on the company's OS X operating system ...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_(web_browser)

Chrome is based on WebKit

WebKit’s HTML and JavaScript code originally began as a fork of the KHTML and KJS libraries from KDE,[3] and has now been further developed by individuals from KDE, Apple Inc., Nokia, Google, Bitstream, RIM, Igalia, and others.[4] OS X, Windows, GNU/Linux, and some other Unix-like operating systems are supported by the project.[5]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit

Comment: @husky To complete the answer to your question: The 20100101 from Firefox seem to refer to the year the Gecko 2.0 engine started its development. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_user_agent_string_reference Also note that: "from Firefox 10 on mobile, geckotrail is the same as the firefox version". Apparently it was 20010725 previously as per: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.productSub Perhaps based on this achievement: http://www.hollyandjeremy.com/siteinfo/help.html